# How to add a Quotation mark to a variable in dart

Tags: dart

I have a variable in declared in flutter and I want to print it as a string with a quotation mark around it something like this:

```
String name = "samuel";

so when I print it out I would get double quotations around it


"Samuel"
```

i tried

```
 print("'" + name +"'")

print('"' + name + '"')

print("\"" + name + "\"")
```

but none worked. Please, how can I achieve this in dart?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- different outer quotes

```
print('"$name"')
print("'$name'") // prints ' quotes
```

- escape quotes

```
print('\"$name\"')
```

Comment: The suggestions in your question should all work (except the first which would print single quotes), but string concatenation with `+` is frowned upon in Dart and you should prefer string interpolation.

Comment: What of an instance when it is an object, and i want to get a property variable from it and add quotation marks to it , such as User.username

Comment: `print('"${obj.prop}"')`